# How to correspond two lists in Python

Tags: python

let's imagine I have:

```
question_list = ['how old are you?', 'how tall are you']
possible_answers = ['15, 14, 19, 32', '1.92cm, 2.01cm, 1.59cm, 1.72cm']
```

I want to be able to correspond 'how old are you?' with '15, 14, 19, 32' so when I print one question from question_list randomized I get the corresponding from possible_answers. How can I do this?

I'm stuck here for context:

```
if random.choice(game_list) == 'trivia':
 question = print(random.choice(question_list))
```

Essentially I want to correspond something from a list with another thing from another list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` to zip them together:

```py
questions_and_answers = list(zip(question_list, possible_answers))

# later when getting an answer
question, answers = random.choice(questions_and_answers)
print("The question is:", question)
print("The possible answers are:", answers)
```

If you want the answers as a list, then split on comma:

```py
answers_list = answers.split(", ")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

your heading in the wrong direction because `print()` does not return anything, you would need to use a variable to store the index because it has to be used twice

```py
if random.choice(game_list) == 'trivia':
    # get random index for question
    question_num = random.randint(0, len(question_list)-1)
    # print question
    print(question_list[question_num])
    # print corresponding answer
    print(possible_answers[question_num])
```